# BigTable Emulator Filter Bug

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

There is a bug in the big table emulator when a conditional filter is run using the python Bigtable library. This bug does not occur when running against the production Bigtable, so I am thinking that the issue is with the emulator.  If the chain does not return any results, then the conditional true filter should not return any results, but that is not the case when the code is run against the emulator.

```sh
# pip list | grep bigtable
google-cloud-bigtable    1.2.0 

# gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 274.0.0
beta 2019.05.17
bigtable 
bq 2.0.51
cbt 
core 2019.12.17
docker-credential-gcr 
gsutil 4.46
kubectl 2019.11.04
```

```py
import os
from google.cloud import bigtable
import google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters as btf

os.environ["BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "localhost:8086"
TEST_PROJECT_NAME = "test-project"
TEST_INSTANCE_NAME = "test-instance"

TEST_TABLE = "test-table"
TEST_FAMILY = "a"

admin_client = bigtable.Client(project=TEST_PROJECT_NAME, admin=True)
admin_inst = admin_client.instance(TEST_INSTANCE_NAME)
tbl = admin_inst.table(TEST_TABLE)
fam = tbl.column_family(TEST_FAMILY)
if not tbl.exists():
    tbl.create()
    fam.create()

# write a row
row = tbl.direct_row("aaa")
row.set_cell(TEST_FAMILY, b'a', '\x01')
row.set_cell(TEST_FAMILY, b'b', '\x05')
row.commit()

chain1 = btf.RowFilterChain([
    btf.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(b'a'),
    btf.ValueRangeFilter(start_value='\x01')
    ])
chain2 = btf.RowFilterChain([
    btf.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(b'b'),
    btf.ValueRangeFilter(start_value='\x09')
    ])

union_filt = btf.RowFilterUnion([chain1, chain2])

chain_filter = btf.RowFilterChain([
    union_filt,
    btf.CellsRowOffsetFilter(1)
    ])

cond_filter = btf.ConditionalRowFilter(
    chain_filter,
    true_filter=btf.PassAllFilter(True))

print("Just union")
for r in tbl.read_rows(filter_=union_filt):
    print(r.cells)

print("Just chain")
for r in tbl.read_rows(filter_=chain_filter):
    print(r.cells)

print("Cond Filter")
for r in tbl.read_rows(filter_=cond_filter):
    print(r.cells)

tbl.delete()
```

Results

```sh
Just union
{'a': {b'a': [<Cell value=b'\x01' timestamp=2019-12-27 19:23:27.402000+00:00>]}}
Just chain
Cond Filter. THIS SHOULD NOT RETURN ANYTHING
{'a': {b'a': [<Cell value=b'\x01' timestamp=2019-12-27 19:23:27.402000+00:00>], b'b': [<Cell value=b'\x05
' timestamp=2019-12-27 19:23:27.402000+00:00>]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible failure case. Can you enter a bug at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues? That's where the emulator is hosted.

Comment: Sure thing, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was confirmed as a bug from comment line in question.

Ref GitHub issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1712